# Diagonalizing a Block Matrix with one non-zero Block column

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to diagonalize $(M+N) \times (M+N)$ matrix

$G\Gamma_LG^\dagger\Gamma_R $$ = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0_{M\times M} & A_{M\times N} \\ 0_{N\times M} & B_{N\times N} \end{array}\right)$

in order to calculate the eigenvectors for the non-zero eigenvalues (i.e. the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues of $B$).

I was essentially wondering if this can be broken down into smaller matrix operations that can avoid having to diagonalize the whole thing at once (computer issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a block matrix the characteristic polynomial is: 
$$ p_{0_{M\times M}}(x)p_{B_{N\times N}}(x)$$
and does not depend to the block $A$.

So yes: you can diagonalize the single diagonal block. Clearly the first is obvious.